# How can I format a date property in case list or case detail

Tags: commcare

I would like to **output a date in a custom format in the case list**.

I have a date property, i.e. date-opened
And it currently displays as, 2017-03-01 (format/ YYYY-MM-DD)

I would like it to output, Mar 01

format-date(date(/data/my_date), "%b %e")

In the case list, I specified the property, 'date-opened'
Under 'format', I select calculate

This syntax caused an application error, identified during the app update  on mobile.

Any suggestions on how to format a date in the case list or case detail are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Is this just an example, or is this verbatim what you have in the case list?

```
format-date(date(/data/my_date), "%b %e")
```

The problem is `/data/my_date` doesn't exist, that's just an example in the documentation that you need to fill with the thing you're trying to reference.  I think you need this:

```
format-date(date(date-opened), "%b %e")
```

This may also work - not sure:

```
format-date(date(.), "%b %e")
```